# Python: Make a class instance from an argument

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Lets say there is a cmd

```
python somefile.py arg
```

somefile contains a definition

```
class CamelCase(object):
```

I want to take the arg and make it a class instance like:

```
arg = CamelCase(whatever_args)
```

the problem is if I use sysarg from os and take it in as arg, wouldnt it be a string?

and then is there any workaround?

Comment: your question is very unclear. what is `arg` exactly? can you give a pseudocode example?

Comment: Like @Elazar said, the question is very unclear. But I think you want to have a look at the eval command.

Comment: Well Koterpillar understood it perfectly.check the accepted answer.that is what i meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want your script to be run as

```
./script.py MyObject
```

and create an instance of `MyObject`.

For this, you can use [globals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals):

```
import sys

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A created"

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B created"

cls = globals()[sys.argv[1]] # Get the class name from globals

instance = cls()
```

Caveats:

- The class has to be imported. It is up to you to parse the namespace and import the required module otherwise.
- You have to carefully verify the input.

Perhaps what you *actually* want is a dictionary of possible arguments and classes, like this:

```
classes = {
    'A': A,
    'B': B,
}

cls = classes[sys.argv[1]]

instance = cls()
```

Comment: THe first solution that you gave is what I am exaclty looking for. What do you mean by class has to be imported. WHere? in the script.py? class will be there in this file itelf.

Comment: THe first solution that you gave is what I am exaclty looking for. What do you mean by class has to be imported. WHere? in the script.py? class will be there in this file itelf. the cls is the argument not a class. cls = Class A(obj) but that is what i wanted.anyway thanks

Comment: For example, this will not work: `./script.py subprocess.Popen`, but if your classes are in the same file, it's OK.

Comment: No what if it is called by bash exec_shell(python mypy.py and_this_arg_i_want where and_this_arg_i_want = MyClass(obj) where MyClass is in mypy.py??

Comment: It will work as long as `and_this_arg_i_want` is in the same file. However, then you end up with `MyClass(obj)()` so `MyClass` has to be callable. Perhaps that is not what you want. Post the whole code if in doubt.